# Do all solid objects emit visible light?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation

Are there solid objects that do **not** emit visible light?

To my limited and humble knowledge, creating such an object would require us to "only" shift the spectrum of emitted radiation. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Cold objects usually do not emit visible light...

Comment: Do you mean *reflect visible light*? All materials emit EM radiation due to black body emission, but at normal temperatures the amount of visible light emitted is negligibly small.

Comment: Good catch. Haven't thought it through really. Those stupid morning thoughts.. :) Thank you all for your response.

Comment: Do perfectly reflecting bodies radiate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The microscopic mechanism of emitting photon in a solid is
the transformation of kinetic energy of atoms into EM energy. If an
atom is in an excited state due to collisions among other atoms, then
it will emit photon when it jumps into the ground state, and the energy
of the photon is
$$
E=\varepsilon(\text{excited state})-\varepsilon(\text{ground state})\sim k_{B}T
$$

The energy of the photon of visible light is about $2\sim3\,\mathrm{eV}$.
So if the temperature $k_{B}T\ll2\,\mathrm{eV}$, then the solid is
difficult to emit visible light. The normal indoor temperature is
$298\,\mathrm{K}$, i.e. $k_{B}T\sim0.025\,\mathrm{eV}$, so it is
difficult to emit visible light in a solid in normal indoor temperature.

Comment: So the emission happens irrespective if a body is in equilibrium with its environment. But if it is in equilibrium the heat that goes to the environment must be equal to the heat that goes into the system from the environment. In that heat we should include radiation?